# How paho client can know status of bridge connections?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have one remote broker (cloudmqtt) and one local broker on my board. Both are connected as bridge. I have one paho client connected to local broker. I want to know the status of bridge in order to publish message. I know I can publish message to local broker without knowing status and broker will take care. But I want to design my application like I will Publish message only if bridge is Up.

I am using paho client library in C and mosquitto broker v1.6.

Below is my conifg file :

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
log_timestamp true
log_timestamp_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
log_type all

user root

connection cloudmqtt 
address xxxx.cloudmqtt.com:13287
remote_username xxxxxxx
start_type automatic
try_private true
remote_password xxxxxx
notifications true
notification_topic /broker/connection/state 
restart_timeout 20
max_queued_messages 0
topic # both 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't at a pure MQTT protocol level or specific to the Paho client (and you shouldn't care for the reasons you mentioned).

Now having said all that you can actually get messages about the bridge status from the `$SYS/broker/connection/<remote-clientid>/#` topic tree on mosquitto. To enable this you need to set the `notification true` flag in the bridge config. The doc for configuring bridges is [here](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html#idm45770162182128)

Comment: So actually I added notification_topic as /broker/connection/state . Notification as True. Now i subscribed same topic on client side but not getting any message.

Comment: first don't start topics with a `/` it's really bad practice. Second why not leave it as the default first to test.

Comment: Ok, now I remove notification_topic and I am getting status of bridge :

Message arrived
     topic: $SYS/broker/connection/mdm9607.cloudmqtt/state
   message: 1
Message arrived
     topic: $SYS/broker/connection/mdm9607.cloudmqtt/state
   message: 0
Message arrived
     topic: $SYS/broker/connection/mdm9607.cloudmqtt/state
   message: 1

But why same message not coming on defined topic? Any inputs.